# Using `version` from Paths_* in a Yesod application

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am trying to write a `GET` handler in Yesod that returns the application version.

Here is the Haskell code for the handler:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Handler.Version where

import qualified Data.Text           as T
import           Data.Version        (showVersion)
import           Import
import           Paths_MyApp         (version)

getVersionR :: Handler Value
getVersionR = return $ object
    [ "version" .= T.pack (showVersion version) ]
```

I added an import in `Application.hs`:

```hs
import Handler.Version
```

and a line in `routes`:

```
/version VersionR GET
```

but I am getting the following error when running `cabal install`:

```
.../MyApp/dist/build/libHSMyApp-0.1.0.a(Version.o):(.text+0xda5):
   undefined reference to `MyAppszm0zi1zi0_PathszuMyApp_version1_closure'
```

I suspect something is missing in my `.cabal` file, but I'm not sure what. I added `Handler.Version` to the `exposed-modules` section, but am wondering if I need to somehow mention the `Paths_*` file.

Answer (score 2):

Solved:

I added

```
Paths_MyApp
```

to the `exposed_modules` section of the `.cabal` file. It now compiles correctly.

Comment: Btw, you can use `yesod add-handler` and Yesod will handle adding the route, handler file, and adding the module to your .cabal file.